# how to convert HTML table to adoc format in adoc

Tags: html, json, asciidoc

I converted JSON to adoc successful with using Swagger2Markup.

but result was not the thing that I intended for.

```
|===
|HTTP Code|Description|Schema
|**200**|● Response<br/><table border=1><tr><td width='20%'>code</td>
...
```

I want to convert HTML Tags in value of JSON to adoc, also.

is there any solution about it?

Comment: There is no general HTML->Asciidoc converter because HTML has features that cannot be converted to Asciidoc. It seems like you are running into a limitation of Swagger2Markup. It would be best if you file an issue for that project, since the HTML you need converted was generated by Swagger2Markup.

Comment: Thanks for answer! my problem happened when I convert adoc to html with using asciidoctor. and I think I missed some points. thank u!